# How to check if "is single" page

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, filters

I know – at first glance the problem may seem easy to solve – and I hope it is – I just can't figure out where/ how to check if I'm really on a single page, or just rendering a single page in the loop.

I basically need to alter the page title of CPT pages. This is what i have tried so far:

```
function event_page_title($title) {

    global $post;

    if ( ( 'event' == $post->post_type ) && ( is_singular() ) ) {

    $title = "Title: " . $title; 

    return $title;

}

add_filter('the_title', 'event_page_title', 0);
```

Problem is: the title is also altered in listings (`WP_query`) – although not in archive pages. I hope somebody can point me some direction? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `is_singular()` with post types like this:

```
if( is_singular('event') ) {
   // We are in single view of event post type
}
```

So, your code could be:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'event_page_title' );
function event_page_title( $title ) {

    if ( is_singular( 'event' ) ) {

        $title = "Title: " . $title;
    }

    return $title;

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I obviously had a misconception about how `is_singular()` works – I tried `is_singular()` before, but without the post type. Now it works like charm.